# NetworkX all_simple_paths gives memory error

Tags: python, networkx

I am using **NetworkX** library for path finding problem for my task. I, certainly need to find the simple paths only. Here is the sample code that I am using:

```
paths = list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, startnode, endnode))
```

Here is the error which the console displays:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run_duc.py", line 130, in <module>
main()
File "run_duc.py", line 78, in main
m1.main()
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\all_model_run_script\abstractive_ilp\main.py", line 119, in main
paths = mygraph.generate_graph(mytext, mystartnode, myendnode, financial_corpus)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\all_model_run_script\abstractive_ilp\graph_node.py", line 241, in generate_graph
paths = self.find_paths(G, self.START, self.END, financial_corpus)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\all_model_run_script\abstractive_ilp\graph_node.py", line 153, in find_paths
paths = list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, startnode, endnode))
MemoryError
```

Comment: How *big* is your graph?

Comment: The case when it gives error contains 1804 nodes

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is because your graph is *too big*. See the [documentation for all_simple_paths()](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/simple_paths.html#all_simple_paths):

> This algorithm uses a modified depth-first search to generate the
>       paths.  A single path can be found in `O(V+E)` time but the
>       number of simple paths in a graph can be very large, e.g. `O(n!)` in
>       the complete graph of order n.

If your graph is *well-connected* (you have many edges) this process might be computationally expensive.

You can try the same method with reducing number of edges in your graph, using [`remove_edges_from()`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.MultiGraph.remove_edges_from.html):

```
In [20]: import networkx as nx

In [21]: g = nx.Graph()

In [22]: g.add_path(range(20))

In [23]: g.edges()
Out[23]:
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10), (10, 11), (11, 12), (12, 13), (13, 14), (14, 15), (15, 16), (16, 17), (17, 18), (18, 19)]

In [24]: g.remove_edges_from( g.edges()[0:10] )

In [25]: g.edges()
Out[25]:
[(10, 11), (11, 12), (12, 13), (13, 14), (14, 15), (15, 16), (16, 17), (17, 18), (18, 19)]
```

If it works with less edges, then it means you don't have enough memory in the first place.

Comment: Well yes, it works fine with smaller graphs. So, I think I should try to split the graph into multiple subgraphs